# HTML5 How to tell when IndexedDB cursor is at end

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, database-cursor

I am iterating thru an indexedDB data store, adding data to a JavaScript array.  How can I tell when the cursor is at the end, so I can sort the array and act on it?

onsuccess is called when a row has been retrieved from the cursor - is there another callback when the entire cursor has been navigated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result (`event.target.result`) of a successful cursor request is either a cursor object or null.

If `event.target.result` is set, it's the cursor, and you can access `event.target.result.value`. You can then call `event.target.result.continue()` to go on to the next object, if any.

If  `event.target.result` is not set, then there are no more objects.

For illustration, some code from a project of mine:

```
  var collectObjects = function (request, cb) {
    var objects = []
    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
      if (!event.target.result) return cb(null, objects)
      cursor = event.target.result
      objects.push(cursor.value)
      cursor.continue()
    }
    request.onerror = function (event) {
      cb(event.target.error)
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what the variable cursor is in your example ( I assume its == not =?)

Comment: No I'm assigning to it, then checking if it exists. I'll modify the example somewhat for readability.

Comment: You got me pointed in the right direction - this worked : if (cursor === false || cursor === undefined) {

Comment: ed4becky, maybe post that code as an extra answer. It's almost impossible to read like this. Can be useful for others.