# Use cursor.continue() in a callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I am trying to use cursor.continue() in chrome.tabs.update() callbacks. I always get the following error.

DOM IDBDatabase Exception 0 Error: A request was placed against a transaction which is either currently not active, or which is finished.

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': TransactionInactiveError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 0 Error: A request was placed against a transaction which is either currently not active, or which is finished.
at chrome-extension://fiipdmhnjimefhdbdfpgllkckomakfkh/sample.js:62:20
at miscellaneous_bindings:288:9
at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:390:21)
at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:376:27)
at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:396:17)
at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:254:22)     event_bindings:380
chrome.Event.dispatch_ event_bindings:380
chrome.Event.dispatch event_bindings:396
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage
```

Code:

```
//background.js
store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
var req;
req = store.count();

req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
  console.log('<p>There are <strong>' + evt.target.result +
                 '</strong> record(s) in the object store.</p>');
                // store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
};
req.onerror = function(evt) {
  console.error("add error", this.error);
 // store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
  //displayActionFailure(this.error);
};

  var i = 0;
req = store.openCursor();
req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
  cursor = evt.target.result;
//store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
  // If the cursor is pointing at something, ask for the data
  if (cursor) {
    //cursor.advance(i);
    console.log("rol cursor:", cursor);
    req = store.get(cursor.key);
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {        
    var value = evt.target.result;                
    chrome.tabs.update(cTab.id,{url:value.uri,active:true},function(t){         
        console.log(value.uri,value.path);    
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(t.id,{file:"/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js",runAt:"document_end"},function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(t.id, { code:"var jClaw = jQuery.noConflict();jClaw('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jClaw('"+value.path+"').offset().top}, 2000);jClaw('"+value.path+"').css({background:'yellow'},1000);",runAt:"document_end"},function(){ 
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(t.id,value.path,function(response){

            cursor.continue();
        });
        });

//cursor.update(cursor.value);
    });
        //cursor.update(cursor.value);
        //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(t.id,"scrollTo");
}); 
    };

    // Move on to the next object in store
    //cursor.continue();
    //cursor.update(cursor.value);

    // This counter serves only to create distinct ids
    i++;
  } else {
    console.log("No more entries");
  }
};
```

I have tried various ways to keep the transaction open. But couldn't succeed.

```
function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
var tx = dbp.transaction(store_name, mode);
tx.oncomplete = function(e){
    console.log("Transaction Complete");
  };
  tx.onabort = function(e){
    console.log("Transaction Aborted");
  };
  tx.onerror = function(e){
    console.log("Transaction Error");
  };
  //tx.onsuccess=keepAlive;
return tx.objectStore(store_name);
}
```

As you can see I want to iterate through indexed DB and use the URL to populate the page. Then I wanted to inject script to fetch some text using message passing. But, if I place cursor.continue() outside callback it's just moving on to next URL as the chrome.tabs.update is async.

Can somebody please help me here?

Comment: See also: [How do you keep an indexeddb transaction alive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385364/how-do-you-keep-an-indexeddb-transaction-alive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexedDB transactions are automatically ended as soon as none of event listeners have queued one or more new operations (modifying data, or moving a cursor). See also: [How do you keep an indexeddb transaction alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385364/how-do-you-keep-an-indexeddb-transaction-alive)

To do async operations which use multiple objects from IndexedDB, you must first collect these objects into an array. See my answer here for quick code. [HTML5 How to tell when IndexedDB cursor is at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639427/html5-how-to-tell-when-indexeddb-cursor-is-at-end) . This code is also more efficient, since it doesn't issue a get request for every single object on the cursor. After all, you can directly access the object at the current position of the cursor by using `cursor.value`.

You may also want to look into how much work you're doing for each object in your database. As it stands now, you're executing a jQuery script each time. You probably want to limit this to just calling `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is `chrome.tabs.update` is async function. `cursor.continue()` must be invoke immediately, i.e., not within async `update` function.

Another point is you don't need `store.get(cursor.key)`. Since you are using value cursor, it value can be obtained by `cursor.value`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! As you can see I want to iterate through indexed DB and use the URL to populate the page. Then I wanted to inject script to fetch some text using message passing. But, if I place cursor.continue() outside callback it's just moving on to next URL as the chrome.tabs.update is async